# Strapi (i18n) API URL Syntax : Locale and Population in the same url

Tags: api, url, locale, strapi, populate

can someone help me with Internalization plug-in in Strapi, I have an issue i cannot find the solution with the documentation :

I would like to do a get request with populate & locale in the same url but impossible to find the right syntax :

[https://admin.flamingophuket.com/api/place-categories?populate[place_subcategories][populate]=places](https://admin.flamingophuket.com/api/place-categories?populate%5Bplace_subcategories%5D%5Bpopulate%5D=places) This is working ✅

https://admin.flamingophuket.com/api/places?locale=ru this is working ✅

[https://admin.flamingophuket.com/api/place-categories?populate[place_subcategories][populate][1]=places&locale=ru](https://admin.flamingophuket.com/api/place-categories?populate%5Bplace_subcategories%5D%5Bpopulate%5D%5B1%5D=places&locale=ru) This is not working ❌

Can someone help me? that would be awsome

Comment: HI @Pierre! Are you sure you have data saved in your Strapi backend with locale=ru? Asking because you mixed places and place-categories....changed the not working url to locale=en and data will be present:
https://admin.flamingophuket.com/api/place-categories?populate[place_subcategories][populate][1]=places&locale=en

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by putting locale first and then populate:

[https://admin.flamingophuket.com/api/place-categories?locale=ru&populate[place_subcategories][populate][1]=places](https://admin.flamingophuket.com/api/place-categories?locale=ru&populate%5Bplace_subcategories%5D%5Bpopulate%5D%5B1%5D=places)

and make sure that the populate has data in the locale requested.